# Multi-checkboxes And Chart Data

Tags: html, chart.js

I try out to create a Data visualization with Chart.js.

My question is quite simple...

I have multi  with different id.

Checking an input "from" to an input "to"

you will able to get data in your chart,

If you check A to B you get some Data, if you check A to C some others... etc...

so I use multi condition to define the data must be shown in my Chart.

here my code,

```
<input id="DFN001" type="checkbox" name="DFN001" onclick="check()" value="from" >From DFN001</li>
```

and my JavaScript

```
<script>

var ctx1 = document.getElementById("chart_1").getContext("2d");
var data = datas1 ;

function validate(){
    var DFN001 = document.getElementById('DFN001');
    if (DFN001.checked){
        datas1 = [10,15,20,85,30,35,40];
    }else{
        alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.")
    }
}



var lineChartData1 = {
            labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
            datasets : [
                {
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data : data
                }
            ]

        }




            document.getElementById('generate_1').onclick = function() 
                {
                    window.myPie = new Chart(ctx1).Line(lineChartData1,{

                responsive: true
            }); 

        };


</script>
```

but when I try it, I get this error... "Uncaught ReferenceError: datas1 is not defined" ...

Can Someone Help me ? or there is and other way do make it ?

thanks a LOT !

Best Regards, and Nice Day,

Mirko

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of program flow related stuff you have to take care of.

`datas1` needs to be initialized before you attempt to set `data` using it. So you need to call `validate()`, not just declare it. In `validate()`, `datas1` will be set only if the checkbox is checked. For now, let's simply check it using HTML (when you add the rest of your code, just remember not to attempt setting `data` unless datas1 is set i.e. the corresponding checkbox is checked)

```
 <input id="DFN001" type="checkbox" name="DFN001" onclick="check()" value="from" checked>From DFN001
```

Calling validate is pretty simple

```
    ...
    validate();

    var ctx1 = document.getElementById...
```

You need to call new Chart to actually render the chart. Something like

```
new Chart(ctx1).Line(lineChartData1);
```

Finally you need to have the canvas element in your HTML (I assume you already have this - just included for completeness)

```
<canvas id="chart_1"></canvas>
```

---

In short, you'll need to call the Chart initialization, `data` initialization, etc. (on your checkbox clicks) keeping the above in mind.

---

Here's a fiddle with all the above changes - http://jsfiddle.net/cy2spqrg/